# AWS EC2 Dns dns resolution issue

Tags: domain-name-system, amazon-web-services

I have created new Amazon instance with 1 Elastic IP.  I have hosted a website on that. after that i had purchased new domain and points my domain to my elastic IP.  When i accessing my domain through my domain name it is got accessible but it is showing my elastic IP in the URL.

Comment: It is really unclear what you are trying to do. Can you past the result of a `curl -v` and tell what part you expect to be different?

Comment: This question has almost certainly been asked before though I have not been able to readily find it.  This is caused by your web server redirecting the browser to what it believes is the correct hostname for the machine.  It should be accompanied by redirects, with a response code in the 30x range, in the web server logs.